# why doesn't func return a string but I can print a string

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def open1(var):
    var  = var.get()
    #print var ----> works
    return var  ----> nothing


var =tk.StringVar()
txtinput = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var,  bg='#FFFFFF', width=25, 
borderwidth=1)
txtinput.grid(column=1, row=1)

button_1 = tk.StringVar()
button = tk.Button(root, textvariable=button_1, command = lambda:open(var), font="Raleway, 10", bg="lightblue", fg="gray")
button_2.set('run')
button.grid(column=1, row=2)

print(open1(var)) ---> nothing
print(var.get()) -----> nothing
```

Tried to print in all diff ways. I am trying to capture an entry from a text field and save it as a variable to use throughout code. It seems to only be able to print to terminal but not save as varible outside the func.

Comment: Your code should fail to run due to exception: `SyntaxError: name 'var' is parameter and global`.

Comment: `open` is a really bad name for a function...

Comment: I added global just to test as its mention on most forums. Open is also a test name. I am just testing here. Do not it works with or without global. Ill remove global from question to avoid other mentions

Comment: You executed the two `print(...)` just after the entry widget is created, so nothing will be shown because nothing is input.

Comment: where would I put the print statement to call it? It is already at the end of the script.

Comment: I also tried adding the button as a function and calling it and THEN printing.... still nothing.

Comment: You're defining a function named `open1` but binding your `Button` to `command=lambda:open(var)`

Comment: I made a change to it based on someone not enjoying the name open. Added a 1. Missed an entry. Doesnt change the issue. Issue is calling variable after button click

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the last two print statements happen well before the user has a chance to click a button, so they can only possible print out the initial value of the variable.

Returning a value from a function called via a button serves no purpose. The value is returned to the internal code of `mainloop`, and it just throws the value away.

If you want a function to generate a value that is usable elsewhere in your code, you'll need to save it in a global variable. If using classes, you can store it in an instance attribute.